# How to create own Login application in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=77) to create a sample Login application using ASP.NET MVC

I have created the database and added it to the Server Explorer as mentioned in the tutorial. I also modified the AccountController.cs file and added the following code instead of the default Logon method.

```
public ActionResult Login(string username, string password, bool? rememberMe)
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
        if (Request.HttpMethod != "POST")
        {
            return View();
        }
        // Basic parameter validation
        List<string> errors = new List<string>();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            errors.Add("You must specify a username.");
        }

        if (errors.Count == 0)
        {

            LinkMVC.Models.LinkManagerDataContext lm = new LinkMVC.Models.LinkManagerDataContext();
            Nullable<int> userid = null;
            lm.fm_AuthenticateUser(username, password, ref userid);

            if (userid > 0)
            {

                FormsAuth.SetAuthCookie(username, rememberMe ?? false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                errors.Add("The username or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }


        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ViewData["errors"] = errors;
        ViewData["username"] = username;
        return View();
    }
```

I am not able to resolve two errors :

> LinkMVC.Models.LinkManagerDataContext lm = new LinkMVC.Models.LinkManagerDataContext();

It says the type of namespace "Models" does not exist in namespace LinkMVC

> FormsAuth.SetAuthCookie(username, rememberMe ?? false);

Here it says no extension method for setAuthCookie

Can someone tell me what I am missing over here?

Thanks

Comment: What is the namespace for your class? is it LinkMVC.Models?

Comment: Where is FormsAuth defined? I think it should be FormsAuthentication.

Comment: @Dallas: namespace is LinkMVC.Models and I have not defined FormsAuth anywhere

Comment: @Dallas: ya it is FormsAuthentication ..so second error solved..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the class should be FormsAuthentication not FormsAuth.

The sample is from 2008 and is using ASP.NET MVC preview 4 so maybe the class name has changed.

Comment: yes right !! see my project name is LinkMVC ..and namespace is LinkMVC.Controllers  as per what I am seeing in my AccountController.cs file

Comment: as per @samich's comment :- is the dbml file in the models folder of the LinkMVC project?

Comment: expand LinkManager.dbml and open the file called LinkManager.cs to see the namespace.

Comment: yes removed that error as well, namespace was LinkMVC.Scripts.Models..but what is "fm_AuthenticateUser' then ? I havent created any method like this? where do i have to create it and how?

Comment: I think it is a stored procedure. The database is created in the authors linq to sql topic http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=74